# Java force fields inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

I know there have been lots of thread about Java inheritance (and i already read it), but they all stand for "how it is", and I need knowledge "how to change it". So, we have 2 classes:

```
class t1{
 public int a=5;

 public void get(){
    System.out.println(a);
 }
}

class t2 extends t1{
 public int a = 1;
}
```

and now :

```
 t2 z = new t2();
 z.get();
```

And we get `5`

Of cource it is just example, but what i want to do is make some common methods in superclass which will use field from inherited class, ex. user messages

Is there any way to do this? If not then why i would use superclasses, can i use anything else?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not inheritance (useful), this is hiding (dangerous)... **Never** hide a variable of a superclass. Somebody will drop a heavy and unforgiving object on your feet at the coffee machine (like the coffee machine itself), as it can cause major pain to know what and why is going on in these cases.

Comment: To be honest I often think it would have been a good decision for java to throw a compliation error when this sort of thing is done

Comment: @RichardTingle My thoughts were a bit _more articulate_, involving people's parents, and their supposed main moneymaking activities, when I solved my first "member variable hiding mistery". That said, I can't agree you more.

Comment: You simply redeclare `a`. This creates a new storage space in `t2` instead of using the field in `t1`. You can't initialize `super` fields in this way. @ppeterka66 short and to the point, as always :)

Comment: You can make an abstract superclass, and force children to implement a method "String getMessage ()", ie;

Comment: @RichardTingle this is so true! i hate that "feature"

Comment: @ppeterka66 i think it should have been removed at all, or made normal override. Why i would use that hiding for? Its looks like this is just variable with same name. Which is somewhat useless.

 @ Falci i actually made something simmilar - made superclass getters abstract and declare them in child class - thanks for hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way do to this. You can apply pattern which called "Template method". Here is an example

```
class Base {

     void someMethod() {
         int value = getValue();

         // calculate something
     }

     protected abstract int getValue();
}

class Derived extends Base {

    int getValue() {
         return 5;
    }
}
```

Where `getValue()` is your template method and you can insert any logic in your inherited classes implementations.

Comment: This is not what i wanted, but it's close enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You should use a constructor and possibly a getter

```
class t1{
 public final int a;

 public t1() {
    this(5);
 }
 protected t1(int a) {
    this.a = a;
 }

 public void get(){
    System.out.println(a);
 }
}

class t2 extends t1{
  public t2() {
     super(1);
  }
}
```

now

```
t2 z = new t2();
z.get();
```

prints `1`

Answer (score 0):

you are shadowing/hiding the variable of `t1`!

`t1` can see the variable of `t2` and prints it's own `a`-value in the get method.

you don't need to declare a again because the a of t1 can be seen everywhere

if you want another default value for `a` in object of type `t2` override the default constructor.

```
public t2() {
    this.a = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism works only for methods, not for fields and you cant change this Java mechanism. It means that [late binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding#Late_binding_in_Java) will find correct body of method depending on class of object

```
class X{
    void sayHello(){
         System.out.println("Hello from X");
    }
}

class Y extends X{
    void sayHello(){
         System.out.println("Hello from X");
    }
}

//...
X obj = new Y();
obj.sayHello();// even if you are using X reference body of method will 
               // come from Y class
```

But fields are not polymorphic so if method uses some field it will use this field all the time (once again, late binding will not search for newest field declared in class of current object). That is why you are seeing `5` as result.

If you want to simulate" polymorphic behaviour of field used in methods body your best choice is to let derived class set new value of that field in base class like in [Peter Lawrey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18874752/1393766) (big +1 for him).